¿Por qué en GoLang, el 'for' no recorre los tipo map de manera sincrónica y retorna un orden distinto en cada ejecución? Por ejemplo:
El siguiente código es espontáneo, al ejecutarlo retorna los días de la semana, el problema es que con cada ejecucion retorna un "orden distinto" de los días y me gustaría entender por qué sucede ésto.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    a := map[string]time.Weekday{
        "s": time.Sunday,
        "m": time.Monday,
        "t": time.Tuesday,
        "w": time.Wednesday,
        "T": time.Thursday,
        "f": time.Friday,
        "S": time.Saturday,
    }

    for key := range a {
        fmt.Println(a[key])
    }
}


Pues lo pone claro en su documentación: the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. Lo que viene a decir mas o menos lo que ya has descubierto: que el ordén de iteración no está garantizado y puede variar de ejecución a ejecución.
